# Issue in type conversion : Explicit type conversion not allowed from unit256 to bytes1

Tags: solidity, remix, design-patterns

I am trying to convert the unit to string using the method. I have the "TypeError" in the line. Please check the screen shot below for the error message.

```
function uint2str(uint i) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    if (i == 0) return "0";
    uint j = i;
    uint length;
    while (j != 0) {
        length++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
    uint k = length - 1;
    while (i != 0) {
        bstr[k--] = byte(48 + i % 10);   ----> this is the place I get error
        i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your error statement to this :

```
bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + i % 10));
```

It will work because of same bit length of both types.

Comment: But i is uint256 .. how I can convert it to uint8 .. there will be data loss

Comment: `i%10` will be a single digit since 0 to 9 always. Adding it to 48 will be in the limit of uint8.

Comment: Great.. I will try and update / accept